# Jquery does not work in Chrome extension tutorial to get and print the entered value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm learning how to write Chrome extensions using [these videos](https://youtu.be/R68_D2AlAR8), the video number 18.

The problem is that when I click on the icon of the extension, and then I enter the amount in the field and click the spend button, nothing happens, and the value is not printed. Also, total spend can not be calculated and limit can not be printed.

Where is the issue? Why the spend button does not work?
Thank you in advance.

Let me mention that I have changed the manifest version from 2 to 3, and changed the order of script tags.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Budget Manager</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.0.6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Budget Manager</h1>
    <h2>Total Spend: <span id="total">0</span></h2>
    <h2>Limit: <span id="limit"></span></h2>
    <h3>Enter Amount</h3>
    <input type="text" id="amount">
    <input type="submit" id="spendAmount" value="Spend">
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
$(function(){

chrome.storage.sync.get(['total', 'limit'], function(budget){
    $('#total').text(budget.total);
    $('#limit').text(budget.limit);
})

$('#spendAmount').click(function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get('total', function(budget){
        var newTotal = 0;
        if (budget.total){
            newTotal += parseInt(budget.total);
        }

        var amount = $('#amount').val();
        if(amount){
            newTotal += parseInt(amount);
        }

        chrome.storage.sync.set({'total': newTotal});

        $('#total').text(newTotal);
        $('#amount').val('');
    });
});
});
```

options.js:

```
$(function(){

chrome.storage.sync.get('limit', function(budget){
    $('#limit').val(budget.limit);
})

$('#saveLimit').click(function(){
    val limit = $('#limit').val();
    if(limit){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'limit': limit}, function(){
            close();
        });
    }
});

$('#resetTotal').click(function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'total': 0})
})
});
```

options.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Budget Manager Options</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Budget Manager Options</h1>
    <h2>Limit: <input type="text" id="limit"></h2>
    <input type="submit" id="saveLimit" value="Save Limit">
    <input type="submit" id="resetTotal" value="Reset Total">
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Budget Manager",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "This extention trackes your overall spendings.",
"icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16": "icon16.png"
},
"action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"options_page": "options.html",

"permissions": [
    "storage"
]
}
```

Comment: 1) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 2) Use `<button>` instead of `input type=submit`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I changed the input to button now. with using the inspect, I still don't understand where is the problem. The only errors I get in the console is "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", which I don't know what and weher are they pointing at exactly.

Comment: 1) go to devtools network panel and press Ctrl-R or F5 to reload the popup to see the bad resource 2) `val limit` should be `var limit`.

Comment: Have you actually included the `jquery-3.6.0.min.js` file into your extension?

Comment: Yes @Xan. I have included the min.js file to another file for another tutorial of that video series and that worked there while I was trying to type on a field and the JS code replaced that with the default text. But here in this tutorial, it does not work.